# KDE Desktop Freezes during Hangout call

Tags: kde

KDE works fine in daily usage, but after making call using Google Hangout for 1 hour or so, it starts freezing for some seconds. The only thing I can do is using the mouse, everything freezes (sound, hangout, chromium, panel etc.).

I tried to change scheduling settings, but it did not help.

What else can I do?

Comment: Remove KDE and install lightdm it works very fine. I'm using it. It doesn't freeze. apt-get install lightdm

Answer (score 0):

I've used KDE on LightDM and there was no such problem on my system. Perhaps you can try installing LightDM and switching display manager, and identifying whether it's a problem with KDE or KDM.

EDIT: As a clarification, I mean to use KDE with LightDM, not to remove KDE as Ruban Savvy has suggested.

Comment: I have lightDM already :/. Should I try GDM?

Comment: Now, that _is_ strange. Sorry, but I don't think I can help you with this problem then :(